# progress bar not update when read firebase records

Tags: firebase, progress-bar, redraw

I use next code to save firebase records to my array list:

```
List<PoIs> LocoList = new ArrayList<>();
DatabaseReference ref = 
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("DATABASE");

ProgressBar progressBar = dialog.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
progressBar.setProgress(0);


    ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {

            int size = (int) dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount();
            progressBar.setMax(size);
           
            for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                PoIs loco = ds.getValue(PoIs.class);
                LocoList.add(loco);

                progressBar.setProgress(LocoList.size());

..........
```

The problem is that my progressbar is updated just at final. Progress bar stay at zero to ten seconds then jump directly to 3000.

Any suggestion how to redraw my progress bar for every setProgress?

Comment: Unfortunately no. I didn't find any solution

Comment: How would you like your ProgressBar to work? From 100%-0% or from 0%-100%?

Comment: From 0 to 100. Sorry for delay!

Comment: How did you define `progressBar` and `itemsList`?

Comment: Updated the code on topic

Comment: I increse the progress bar using list size 
    PoIs loco = ds.getValue(PoIs.class);
    LocoList.add(loco);
    progressBar.setProgress(LocoList.size());

Comment: Have you tried to get the last if statement out of the for loop?

Comment: don't know how.

Comment: Move it right where the for loop ends.

Comment: if I move after loop ending I will get just the last value.